# Trigger functions in different components with a buttonclick via service in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, mean

I have a dashboard, where I can type in data in a component and the data is going in a mongoDB. Then I get that data in other components and display it at the same site. Now I just have an update button under each component, that I can manually update every component. But I want to do that in this moment, where I submit my data, that is going to mongodb.

I tried it with a service, but it didn't worked out very well

**This should be updated**

```
import { UpdateServicenter code heree} from "../../../@core/data/update.service";

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private updateService: UpdateService,) {
              //load it the first time if you refreshing the site
              this.updateOrders();
              //this should call updateOrders again if button is clicked
              this.updateService.updateData()
}

updateOrders() {
              //here I get the data from mongoDB and set it in my variables
}
```

**Button** (This function is called, if I push the button)

```
import { UpdateService} from "../../../@core/data/update.service";

constructor(private http: HttpClient,private updateService: UpdateService){}          
submitButton(){
              this.updateService.updateData()
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()

export class UpdateService {
   updateData(){
        //this should call the function updateOrders()
   }
}
```

I want to create a service, that can call every function or can be called, if the button is pushed, because I have more than one component which should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

the method updateOrders() is an http call where you receive an observable object?

Comment: yes and I also subscribe it and set the data in variables to use it in html

Comment: Great. Move this method into the service, save your data into variables in the service and then pass the data as input to each component, like this the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook will fire each time your data gets updated. e.g.
UpdateService

Answer (score 0):

Great. Move this method into the service, save your data into variables in the service and then pass the data as input to each component, like this the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook will fire each time your data gets updated. e.g.

```
@Injectable()

export class UpdateService {
   public obj; //variable you save your data

   updateOrders() {
             this.someObj = this.http<>.....
  }
 getObj():{
  // do your stuff here if you need so
   return this.obj;
  }
}

<someComp [obj]="updateService.getObj()"></someComp>

export class SomeComponent {
   @Input()
   public obj;

   ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
      //do your stuff here if you need so, or hust send them to html
    }
}
```

Comment: Big thanks to you! My mainproblem was just, that I've forgot to set the values in the service to public lol. Sometimes there are so simple things, that let you stuck some hours. But I also understand the service structure better because of your comment :)

Comment: These small simple things are doing the harm in our code, because they are not easily traced. Please upvote my response as helpful, if it really helped you:)